# Quadratic Equation Solver in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

For some reason, when a=1, b=1, c=-1, I am not getting the desired result of -1.6180339887499 and 0.61803398874989. Instead, I get 2 and 1. What am I doing wrong?

```js
function solve(a,b,c){
    var result = (((-1*b) + Math.sqrt(Math.pow(b,2)) - (4*a*c))/(2*a));
    var result2 = (((-1*b) - Math.sqrt(Math.pow(b,2)) - (4*a*c))/(2*a));
    
    return result + "<br>" + result2;
}

document.write( solve(1,1,-1) );
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need another grouping:

```
var result = (((-1 * b) + Math.sqrt(Math.pow(b, 2)) - (4 * a * c)) / (2 * a));  // wrong
var result2 = (((-1 * b) - Math.sqrt(Math.pow(b, 2)) - (4 * a * c)) / (2 * a)); // wrong
```

vs

```
var result = (-1 * b + Math.sqrt(Math.pow(b, 2) - (4 * a * c))) / (2 * a);      // right
var result2 = (-1 * b - Math.sqrt(Math.pow(b, 2) - (4 * a * c))) / (2 * a);     // right
```

All together:

```js
function solve(a, b, c) {
    var result = (-1 * b + Math.sqrt(Math.pow(b, 2) - (4 * a * c))) / (2 * a);
    var result2 = (-1 * b - Math.sqrt(Math.pow(b, 2) - (4 * a * c))) / (2 * a);
    return result + "<br>" + result2;
}
document.write(solve(1, 1, -1));
```

Comment: maybe you have a look here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/103344/unfoiling-quadratic-equation

Comment: This is great!  Unfortunately I'm using this to graph a line that never quite reaches zero so it returns NAN.  How would I modify this so that it would return the x intercept for when y equals some other number that zero.  Such as 10?

Comment: @Squirrl, do you have an example?

Comment: Sure "y = 0.05x^2 + -7.84x + 366.67"

Comment: you could use [logical OR `||`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_OR_()) with zero and replace `NaN` values with zero. (if that is, what you want.)

Comment: I know for instance that if I set x to 100, `.05*100*100 + -7.84*100 + 366.67 = 82.67` but how can i find the reverse? For instance what x would be if y was equal to 82.67?

Comment: I think this may be more of a math question than a js question, but I'm not sure how to google it.

Comment: Ahh I just minus the 82.67 from the c variable?? ahh I'm sorry that was silly.  I think that's it.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
var a, b, c, discriminant, root1, root2, r_Part, imag_Part;

document.write(realpart ="+r_Part" and imaganary part ="+imag_Part");
discriminant = b*b-4*a*c;


if (discriminant > 0)
{
    root1 = (-b+sqrt(discriminant))/(2*a);
    root2 = (-b-sqrt(discriminant))/(2*a);

document.write(real part ="+r_Part" and imaganary part ="+imag_Part");   
}

else if (discriminant == 0)
{
    root1 = root2 = -b/(2*a);
   document.write(real part ="+r_Part" and imaganary part ="+imag_Part");
}


else
{
    r_Part = -b/(2*a);
    imag_Part = sqrt(-discriminant)/(2*a);
    document.write(real part ="+r_Part" and imaganary part ="+imag_Part");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function solve(a, b, c) {
    var result = ((-1 * b + Math.sqrt(Math.pow(b, 2) - (4 * a * c))) / (2 * a)).toFixed(3);
    var result2 = ((-1 * b - Math.sqrt(Math.pow(b, 2) - (4 * a * c))) / (2 * a)).toFixed(3);
    return "{"+result + "," + result2+"}";
}
document.write(solve(1, -4, -7));
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <title></title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="">
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        var a=2;
            var b=9;
            var c=2;
    
            var root_part=Math.sqrt(b*b-4*a*c);
            var denom=2*a;
            
            if (isNaN(root_part) === true){
                document.write("<br> Impossible to solve");
            }
            else{
            var root1=(-b+root_part)/denom;
            var root2=(-b-root_part)/denom;
            document.write("<br>First Root is="+root1+ " and Second Root is="+root2); 
            }
        </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).